# Matplotlib - Correlation plots with different range of numbers but on same scale

Tags: matplotlib, plot, colors, scale, correlation

I would like to have a 2 by 3 figure with 6 correlation plots, sharing the same scale, even when the values in the plots have different ranges. Below you can see what I have so far.

[image]

In the first column, the values range from 0 to 1, with 1 on the diagonal, and close to 0 elsewhere. For the other two columns it holds for the top row that the values range from 0 to 1, whereas the values in the bottom row range from -1 and 1. The difference between the second and third column is that the values in the second column are around 0.3 (and -0.3) and the values in the third column are around 0.7 (and -0.7).

As you can see, several things seem to be going incorrect. First of all, although I want them all to be plotted according to the same color scale, with dark blue being -1 and yellow being 1, this is clearly not the case. If this would hold, we would have bright blue/greenish in the first column. What could I do to indicate the range for the colors? Next, how do I change the labels of the color scale on the right? I would like it to range from -1 to 1.

Below, you find my implementation.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3, figsize=(15,8))
idx_mixed = {False: 0, True: 1}
idx_rho = {0: 0, 0.3: 1, 0.7: 2}
for mixed in [False, True]:
    for rho in [0, 0.3, 0.7]:
        ax[idx_mixed[mixed]][idx_rho[rho]].matshow(results[mixed][rho])

ax[0][0].set_title("No correlation", pad=20, fontsize=14)
ax[0][1].set_title("Weakly correlated", pad=20, fontsize=14)
ax[0][2].set_title("Strongly correlated", pad=20, fontsize=14)
ax[0][0].set_ylabel("Positive correlations", fontsize = 14)
ax[1][0].set_ylabel("Mixed correlations", fontsize = 14)
fig.colorbar(mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(), ax=fig.get_axes())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a `norm=` argument to `matshow()` so that the data is scaled to the range [-1, 1] rather than a range defined by the min and max value present in the data. See [Colormap Normalization](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html#colormap-normalization) for more details.

```
cmap = 'viridis'
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=-1, vmax=1)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,3)
for ax, d in zip(axs.flat, data):
    m = ax.matshow(d, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
fig.colorbar(m, ax=axs)
```

[image]